# How do I get both indexPath.row and indexPath.section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

Whenever the user inputs something in a new section, the indexpath.row for the previous sections gets replaced with the new row of the section. I will give you an example to understand better what I'm trying to say:

I have a tableview like this:

Section 1:

1. User input #1
2. User input #2

Now the user creates a new Section. (Section 2). When he inputs a row for the Section 2, the tableview turns into

Section 1:

1. User input #3
2. User input #2

Section 2:

1. User input #3

The user again adds another input:

Section 1:

1. User input #3
2. User input #4

Section 2:

1. User input #3
2. User input #4

So the rows for the previous sections gets replaced by the new rows. I found where all of this comes from but I don't know how to fix it. The problems come from this line of code:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expenseCell") as? ExpenseCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    let budget = userBudget[indexPath.row] // <- This
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.configureCell(budget: budget)
    return cell
}
```

Because only the indexPath.row is given, not the indexPath.section. My question is, how do I add a cell for indexPath.section and indexPath.row ?

I tried modifying `let budget = userBudget[indexPath.row]`

with `let budget = userBudget[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`
 but it says `Type 'Budget' has no subscript members`

> var userBudget : [Budget] = []

and `Budget` is a CoreData Entity

Comment: What fields does `Budget` have?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/4WsP6Ze.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your array. Your array must be nested array.

For e.g.

```
var userBudget: [[Budget]] = []
```

Change your cellForRowAt indexPath function like below:

```
let budget = userBudget[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
cell.delegate = self
cell.configureCell(budget: budget)
```

NOTE: Add "array of Budget" in userBudget instead of "Budget".
"array of Budget" is describe as section.

Simple example of Array of Array of String:

```
var userBudget: [[String]] = [
                                ["Section 1 - User input #1","Section 1 - User input #2","Section 1 - User input #3"],  //Section 1 Inputs
                                ["Section 2 - User input #1","Section 2 - User input #2"],                              //Section 2 Inputs
                                ["Section 3 - User input #1","Section 3 - User input #2"]                               //Section 3 Inputs
                             ]
```

Comment: I did what you said but now whenever I add a new input my apps crashes, says index out of bounds

Comment: This totally blurred me out. How do I see how many arrays I have in userBudget? Because it stays 1 all the time no matter how many inputs I give.